# Preview Post before save in active admin

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I am looking for some pointers on getting started with this feature; I would like a user to be able to preview what their post would look like if saved

```
ActiveAdmin.register Post do
  permit_params :comments, :title, :category_id, :slug, :published
  # Create Blog Post
  form do |f|
    inputs 'Blog' do
      f.semantic_errors
      f.input :title
      f.input :category_id, as: :select, collection: Category.all
      f.input :comments, as: :text, input_html: { rows: 10, cols: 10 }
      f.input :published, as: :boolean
    end
     inputs 'Submit' do
      f.actions
     end
  end

end
```

So looking at the active admin documentation I can see you can add `custom action items`

```
action_item :preview, only: :new, name: 'preview_button' do
  # do stuff here
end
```

I can also add a custom controller action in the form of a collection_action which will also add a route for me

```
collection_action :preview, method: :post do
  @post = Post.new(params[:post])
end
```

So now I have a custom action `preview` and a button that can pass data to the method (I have hard coded it for now, as unsure how to get the data from outside the form).

This is what I have so far:

```
action_item :preview, only: :new, name: 'preview_button' do
   link_to 'Preview', preview_my_admin_panel_posts_path(post: { title: 'Test Title', comments: 'test comments', category_id: '1' })
end

# Add controller action
collection_action :preview, method: :get do
  @post = Post.new(params[:post_params])
end
```

My view gets rendered but nothing gets outputted, how do I then show the data?

Is this the correct approach?

### Update

Can now show the hardcoded data with

```
collection_action :preview, method: :get do
  @post = Post.new(permitted_params[:post])
end
```

The difference being in the active admin docs

> The permit_params call creates a method called permitted_params. You should use this method when overriding create or update actions:

Now I just need to grab the form data outside the form and pass it through my link_to and then be able to keep the form populated with the same data if I go back to the form.

Ideally I would like to have the preview button within the f.actions as then I would have access to the @post object.